# filtering out history based on dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server reporting tools 2008 and have created a table as below.

I have a dataset that produces the following results.  Basically every time the charge field changes within the database the table is given a ceased date for the current charge and then a new effective date for the new charge.  This normally results in there being a blank ceased date. (eg UCN 1 and UCN 495)   If there has never been a charge applied then you also get a blank ceased date. (eg UCN 11)

I found that if you use the year function below as a calculated field, you get a result of 1 for a blank field and then can use the filter function to include "1" only to find all of the current charges.

```
=Year(Fields!CEASED_DATE.Value)
```

Under a certain set of circumstances though, and in this case UCN 492 doesn't get a new effective date and therefore has no blank ceased date.  In a 40,000 record database this only occurs 100 times.

What I want to do is list every UCN in the database with its current charge, or leave the field blank if there is no charge current.  Basically I want to filter out the history.

Is this possible?

```
UCN......CEASED_DATE....EFFECTIVE_DATE.....Charge  

1........12 July 2009...11 July 2009.......Rate 3  
1.......................12 July 2009.......Rate 4  

11  

492......12 July 2009...01 January 1900....Rate 4  
492......15 July 2009...12 July 2009.......Rate 5  
492......31 July 2011...15 July 2009.......Rate 2  

495......12 April 2009..04 November 1946...Rate 2  
495.....................12 April 2009......Rate 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the following function in a `UCN` only grouped tablix in reporting services?

```
=max(iif(year(Fields!CEASED_DATE.Value)=1, Fields!CHARGE.Value, ""))
```

Or in the dataset similar to?

```
Select UCN,
   Max(case when ceased_date = '' then charge else '' end) current_charge
From charges
Group by UCN
```

Comment: Hi  Yes the tablix option works which is a big help with the function above.  Getting this to work is part of large overall report, which I have started to do in a table, rather than a tablix.  Having put that function into a column I then need to filter it I think, but I can't filter it on blank fields as I would lose the all important records 11 and 492.  Any advice here before I change to a tablix?  Thanks

Comment: Basically it is suppression of the multi lines of data based on the above expression, but when blank, keep one of those lines, exactly what a tablix does but within a table

Comment: I don't believe you can do this as a filter on the dataset. I think the only way is to alter your query if possible, or use a filering technique in the tablix.